# Create a repetitive value a certain number of times if the value does not meet a certain count in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I wish to create a repetition of a certain value if and only if the value does not already repeat by a certain number.

**Data**

```
id  Date    type    energy
aa  Q1 22   hi      5
aa  Q2 22   hi      5
aa  Q3 22           0
aa  Q4 22           0
aa  Q1 23   hi      5
aa  Q1 23   hi      5
aa  Q1 23   hi      5
aa  Q1 23   hi      5
aa  Q1 23   hi      5
bb  Q1 23   hi      2
```

**Desired**

```
id  Date    type    energy
aa  Q1 22   hi      5
aa  Q2 22   hi      5
aa  Q3 22           0
aa  Q4 22           0
aa  Q1 22           0
aa  Q1 22           0
aa  Q1 22           0
aa  Q1 22           0
aa  Q2 22           0
aa  Q2 22           0
aa  Q2 22           0
aa  Q2 22           0
aa  Q3 22           0
aa  Q3 22           0
aa  Q3 22           0
aa  Q3 22           0
aa  Q4 22           0
aa  Q4 22           0
aa  Q4 22           0
aa  Q4 22           0
aa  Q1 23   hi      4
aa  Q1 23   hi      3
aa  Q1 23   hi      4
aa  Q1 23   hi      3
aa  Q1 23   hi      3
bb  Q1 23   hi      2
bb  Q1 23           0
bb  Q1 23           0
bb  Q1 23           0
bb  Q1 23           0
```

**Logic**

```
If 'Date'  value does not repeat at least 5 times, 
then repeat 5 times with a value of '0' in the energy column. 
If Date value repeats at least 5 times, then do nothing. (i.e. 'aa' Q1 23)
 - we see that this already repeats 5 times, so no change occurs.
```

**Doing**

```
result = df['Date'].repeat(repeats = 5)
df['energy'] = 0
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: You may first get `df[['id', 'Date']].value_counts()` and then keep only the `id`-`Date` combinations which has less than 5 counts. With that remaining list, you can know what to repeat.

Comment: Ok will try thank you @RaymondKwok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert `df` into an array and use `np.repeat` to replicate rows. To conditionally repeat, calculate the repeat frequency using `groupby()`, `transform`. Convert the output array back into `df` using the `pd.DataFrame()` constructor

```
   s=df.groupby(['Date','id'])['type'].transform('count')

s=np.where(s.ge(5),0,abs(pd.Series(s)-5))

new=pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df.values,s, axis=0), columns=df.columns)

new=(df.append(new.assign(type=np.nan, energy=0)).fillna('').sort_values(by=['id','type','Date'], ascending=[True,False, False]))

  id   Date type  energy
1   aa  Q2 22   hi       5
4   aa  Q1 23   hi       5
5   aa  Q1 23   hi       5
6   aa  Q1 23   hi       5
7   aa  Q1 23   hi       5
8   aa  Q1 23   hi       5
0   aa  Q1 22   hi       5
3   aa  Q4 22            0
12  aa  Q4 22            0
13  aa  Q4 22            0
14  aa  Q4 22            0
15  aa  Q4 22            0
2   aa  Q3 22            0
8   aa  Q3 22            0
9   aa  Q3 22            0
10  aa  Q3 22            0
11  aa  Q3 22            0
4   aa  Q2 22            0
5   aa  Q2 22            0
6   aa  Q2 22            0
7   aa  Q2 22            0
0   aa  Q1 22            0
1   aa  Q1 22            0
2   aa  Q1 22            0
3   aa  Q1 22            0
9   bb  Q1 23   hi       2
16  bb  Q1 23            0
17  bb  Q1 23            0
18  bb  Q1 23            0
19  bb  Q1 23            0
```

Comment: Hi @wwnde thank you but some of these values shouldn’t have repeated ‘hi’ and the ‘energy’ values should  be ‘0’ - will look it over

Comment: Lets try that one

Comment: Ok will try this thank you

Answer (score 1):

First build a dataframe of missing rows then merge with your original dataframe:

```
cat = pd.CategoricalDtype(df['Date'].unique(), ordered=True)

# Step-1
df1 = df[['id', 'Date']].value_counts(sort=False).clip(1, 4).rsub(5) \
                        .to_frame('repeat').assign(type='', energy=0).reset_index()
df1 = df1.reindex(df1.index.repeat(df1['repeat'])).drop(columns='repeat')

# Step-2
out = pd.concat([df, df1]).astype({'Date': cat}) \
        .sort_values(['id', 'Date']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
    id   Date type  energy
0   aa  Q1 22   hi       5
1   aa  Q1 22            0
2   aa  Q1 22            0
3   aa  Q1 22            0
4   aa  Q1 22            0
5   aa  Q2 22   hi       5
6   aa  Q2 22            0
7   aa  Q2 22            0
8   aa  Q2 22            0
9   aa  Q2 22            0
10  aa  Q3 22            0
11  aa  Q3 22            0
12  aa  Q3 22            0
13  aa  Q3 22            0
14  aa  Q3 22            0
15  aa  Q4 22            0
16  aa  Q4 22            0
17  aa  Q4 22            0
18  aa  Q4 22            0
19  aa  Q4 22            0
20  aa  Q1 23   hi       5
21  aa  Q1 23   hi       5
22  aa  Q1 23   hi       5
23  aa  Q1 23   hi       5
24  aa  Q1 23   hi       5
25  aa  Q1 23            0
26  bb  Q1 23   hi       2
27  bb  Q1 23            0
28  bb  Q1 23            0
29  bb  Q1 23            0
30  bb  Q1 23            0
```